# Indenting the whole easylist

Tags: minipage, easylist, adjustwidth

I want to indent an easylist under a `\subparagraph` so that it looks the same way as it would be under regular `\paragraph`.

Doing `\indent\begin{easylist}` doesn't work, the indent size is the same as for `\subparagraph`. But I want it to be double the size. I tried to do it with `minipage` which doesn't really work. The closest thing I found is using `\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5cm}{0cm}`, but the first item is bit more indented then the rest.

PS I wanted to leave here a example, but for some reason the example works, even tho it's just simplified version of what I'm working on... so, I just really don't know why is the first item indented more than the others.

PPS if there is a simpler way of doing this please let me know!

Comment: Welcome! Since `easylist` uses low level methods for indenting the various lists, it cannot work inside `adjustwidth`.

Comment: @egreg It did work in really simple example (just 3 items). Anyway how would you indent ti then?

Comment: Try the enumitem package which lets you control how lists look.

Comment: @PeterFlynn I don't think that it works with easy list, but I discovered that easy list itself has some margin setting so I'm going to look into that